# What is an effective separator for adjoining steel sinks divided into meat and dairy?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

[Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/82667/jewish/Koshering-Your-Kitchen.htm) recommends:
"...Separate sinks for washing dishes and preparing foods are recommended. If the two sinks are adjoining, there should be an effective separation between them so that no water or food splashes from one sink to the other..."

Some steel sinks are divided into two halves, with a swivel faucet, that one could designate meat and the other dairy.  What considerations should I give in constructing an effective separator.  Droplet size and distance tends to vary randomly with the majority of the droplets most likely to fall into the proper sink.  How large should the divider be to prevent accidental spillage?

Comment: How could anyone answer this? We don't know how accurate a pourer you are, what kinds of things you pour, etc. Are you using large pots (big family, restaurant, etc.)? Why would you think there is some generally applicable answer here?